# Is there any way of configuring Oracle ATG to load java class changes dynamically?

Tags: jboss, atg

I am interested in setting up a development environment for ATG in which changes on class will take effect immediately after the build is done, without restarting server and building again the ear file.

I have searched in the product documentation but the only thing I saw you can configure to load dynamically would be the configuration files section.

Is there any other way of configuring the environment for better productivity?

Comment: Which Application Server are you using and which IDE? If you are running in debug mode it is possible to do hotswapping of classes but it is not reliable. I've had mixed successes with this in Eclipse and WebSphere/Jboss. Not so much in WebLogic. Otherwise get JRebel.

Comment: @radimpe ,thx for your answer. I am using Jboss and Eclipse. By default, the application is deployed as an ear, so it is already packed. Even though JRebel may be a solution, in my case, I am required to stick to Jboss and find a way to live deploy on this too.

Comment: Have a look at the [run-in-place](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGPlatformProgGuide/html/s0304commandoptions01.html) option for assembling JBoss EARs

Answer (score 1):

Use [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/). That will do dynamic re-loading for java classes, property files and other deployable assets. Great for productivity.

Comment: Thx for the reply. Even though JRebel may be a solution, in my case, I am required to stick to Jboss and find a way to live deploy on this too.

Comment: JRebel is a Java agent, not an application server. It works with JBoss too.

Comment: Thanks, I will give JRebel a try, but I believe I will stick to the @GaneshChaitanya 's suggestion if it will work for me (mostly because it is free).

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose is to debug and most of time is getting wasted packing and unpacking the ear, you can always use remote debugging with JBoss and Eclipse, but for major changes like adding a method wont be working in that case. One solution to this is use Java DCEVM which will dynamically update code in the JVM. Its a simple jdk just point your Java_home to this jdk and in debug mode you can add code to you class see changes. Use the below link for more information about DCEVM

https://github.com/dcevm/dcevm

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I want to give it a try. I understand from the link you posted that there are Java version limitations. From your experience, will it work for Java versions bellow 6?

Comment: I have not tried with various versions of Java. I used it with Java 7.